# codename one mediaplayer not working on android device

Tags: java, android, codenameone

i am creating a mediaplayer app which is supposed to stream mp3 files from remote url.the problem is that the everything works fine on the codename one simulator but not on an actual android device.I want the app to show native player controls like on the simulator.below is my code and screenshots

```
 try {
      video = MediaManager.createMedia(sample_url,true);
       Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
                if (mp != null){
                    mp.getMedia().cleanup();
                }
                Image samp = theme.getImage("sample.png");
                Label samlabel = new Label();
                samlabel.setIcon(samp);
                mp = new MediaPlayer(video);
                mp.setAutoplay(false);
                video.setNativePlayerMode(true);
                sample.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,BorderLayout.centerAbsolute(samlabel));
                sample.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,mp);
                 //songDetails.add(mp);

            });
```

[image: this is what it looks like on the simulator]

[image: this is what it looks like on the device]

the first image is the simulator screenshot and the second image is the actual android device screenshot

Comment: this doesn't quite explain your issue is it just an image issue? and missing the grey bar thing? also I think you'll need to include mmore code as this seems tto not include where your issue is it might be better expained with the same song for both in the images

Comment: my issue is the missing gray bar which has the native player controls.it works on the simulator but not on the actual device thus the user cannot stream the sample before downloading the song

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your post if this is an `mp3` which is audio and doesn't have media control or an actual video. The `MediaPlayer` class is strictly for video and you passed `true` to indicate that this is a video file so I'll treat it as such.

Notice that if this is an audio file then you need to add/create your own controls and shouldn't use the `MediaPlayer` class.

We recently defined behaviors for native media control rendering as explained [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/media-controls-print-developer-guide.html).

Just use:

```
video.setVariable(Media.VARIABLE_NATIVE_CONTRLOLS_EMBEDDED, true);
```

Comment: it's actually an audio file. do you have any tutorials,demo or code samples I can use to create my own controls because I Am a little bit stuck

Comment: Just add buttons for play/pause etc. The play calls "start" and the "pause" button invokes stop on the media etc.

Comment: does cn1 have any listeners I can use to update a label (timer ) while the file is playing

Comment: We only have a completion callback at this time but you can use a `UITimer` to update the display elements.